# Pasar correctamente los datos a un select vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Como podría obtener correctamente los datos? Estoy intentando obtener los datos con el siguiente formato `1997 - 1998 CI`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El select al cual le estoy pasando los datos que se encuentran en base, en el cual llamo al metodo `getPeriodoMalla` que tengo en el script

```
<select v-model="periodoLectivo" class="form-control col-md-12" @click="getPeriodoMalla()">
    <option v-for="periodo in arrayPeriodo" :key="periodo">{{periodo}}</option>
</select>
```

El script

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            periodoLectivo: '',
            pAcademInicio: '',
            cicloInicio: '',
            arrayPeriodo: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getPeriodoMalla() {
            let me = this;
            var url = '/mallamaterias/periodolectivo';
            axios.get(url).then(function(response) {
                var respuesta = response.data;
                me.arrayPeriodo = respuesta.periodo;

                me.pAcademicoInicio = arrayPeriodo[0]['pAcademicoInicio'];
                me.pAcademicoFin=arrayPeriodo[0]['pAcademicoFin'];
                me.cicloLectivoInicio=arrayPeriodo[0]['cicloLectivoInicio'];

                me.periodoLectivo = me.pAcademicoInicio + ' - ' +me.pAcademicoFin + ' ' + me.cicloLectivoInicio;

                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia en tu `option` el objeto que estás intentando usar como `key` por el uso de una clave que tiene valor único que para este caso sería el `id` de este modo:

```
<option v-for="periodo in arrayPeriodo" :key="periodo.id">{{periodo}}</option>
```

En la documentación de [VueJS](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) se menciona que y cito:

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements

Que se pudiera traducir como:

> Darle una pista a Vue y así pueda rastrear la identidad de cada nodo, para que así se puedan reordenar y reusar los elementos existentes.

Así mismo considera usar **valores de tipo numérico o cadena de texto** como valores de la directiva **`:key`** que formarían parte del grupo de valores primitivos de JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto la solución en base a al comentario de @Aprendiz y a la documentación de vue

pase de esto

```
<select v-model="periodoLectivo" class="form-control col-md-12" @click="getPeriodoMalla()">
 <option v-for="periodo in arrayPeriodo" :key="periodo">{{periodo}}</option>
</select>
```

a esto

```
<<select v-model="periodoLectivo" class="form-control col-md-12" @click="getPeriodoMalla()">
<option v-for="periodo in arrayPeriodo" :key="periodo.id">
    {{periodo.pAcademicoInicio }}  - {{ periodo.pAcademicoFin }} {{ periodo.cicloLectivoInicio }}
</option>
```